# Tools to automate calculation of cyclomatic complexity in java?

Tags: java, cyclomatic-complexity

Are there any tools available for Java that can automagically determine the cyclomatic complexity of given Java code? I have sought out tools online, and have yet to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Sonar (my preferred method). There are plugins to "automagically" generate the report at build time (i.e. ANT/Maven, etc...).

Another related post on how to show the CC on the dashboard: [how to list methods with most cyclomatic complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383779/how-to-list-methods-with-most-cyclomatic-complexity)

One other tool I've used in the past is corbetura. You have to have good unit tests though and finding the quantitative analysis for CC is a little tricky.

Answer (score 0):

One of the metrics produced by [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) is [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Metric+Definitions#JavaMetricDefinitions-Complexity).
I believe it also has an Eclipse plugin (but I haven't managed to find it yet)

Answer (score 0):

AgitarOne from Agitar Technologies (http://www.agitar.com/solutions/products/agitarone.html) calculates cyclomatic complexity in their dashboard report and with their code rules plugin in Eclipse.  Note also that McCabe IQ from McCabe Software (http://www.mccabe.com), a sister company of Agitar Technologies, also calculates cyclomatic complexity (aka McCabe complexity) for Java and has an Eclipse plugin for project setup.